# Is there a documented XD postMessage proxy for Google Drive API's?

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm writing a [client side interface](http://adodson.com/hello.js/) for the Google Data API, whilst trying to avoid using any proprietary Javascript SDK on offer.

I have made successful XHR2 and JSONP GET requests, but am drawing a blank when it comes to POST'ing multipart messages with files attached. I see from prying into the [Javascript SDK](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-js) that its using an iframe and proxy.html and presumably postMessage to circumnavigate the same origin issues. I am unaware of a way to detect postMessage's  communications.

Is the XD postMessage hack documented anywhere?

Thanks
Andrew

Comment: I think that all of google api sdk are Apache 2 Licensed, thus not proprietary.

Comment: Sure, there's probably a better word for it. I mean to say that their Javascript SDK only works with Google services. Their Javascript SDK namespace for instance is "gapi", its not pitched as a product that would work with another webservice without modification.

Comment: OK, thank you for the clarification. I can't help you on our question though =)